# How to use linq and string.EndsWith(<1 of N items in an array>)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an expression as above in the title. Is it possible to use linq to iterate through an array and evaluate if true or not. example
`string[] a = {"es","ag"}`

```
if (string.EndsWith(<1 of N items in a>)==true){//do something}
```

Comment: Ends with what? There should be string to verify

Comment: How many items your `a` array have? How about just `string.EndsWith("es") || string.EndsWith("ag")` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül a.Length is typically large. making || very inefficient to use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (a.Any(yourString.EndsWith))
{
    //your string ends with one of those endings.
}
```